# how do I combine xml nodes with certain conditions using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, conditional-statements

I have two XML documents I want to combine.

forSale.xml:

```
<forSale>
<game>
    <cover>me3_cover.jpg</cover>
    <title>Mass Effect 3</title>
    <publisher>Electronic Arts</publisher>
    <developer>BioWare</developer>
    <genre>Role-Playing</genre>
    <releaseDate>
        <yyyy>2012</yyyy>
        <mm>03</mm>
        <dd>06</dd>
    </releaseDate>
    <esrbRating>M</esrbRating>
    <platforms>
        <platform>X360</platform>
        <platform>PC</platform>
        <platform>PS3</platform>
        <platform>WIIU</platform>
    </platforms>
</game>
<!--more games-->
</forSale>
```

reviews.xml:

```
<reviews>
<game>
    <title>Mass Effect 3</title>
    <review>
        <critic>Kevin VanOrd</critic>
        <synopsis>
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
        </synopsis>
        <pros>
            <pro><![CDATA[some data]]></pro>
            <pro><![CDATA[some data]]></pro>
            <pro><![CDATA[some data]]></pro>
            <pro><![CDATA[some data]]></pro>
            <pro><![CDATA[some data]]></pro>
        </pros>
        <cons>
            <con><![CDATA[some data]]></con>
            <con><![CDATA[some data]]></con>
        </cons>
        <content>
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
            <p />
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
            <p />
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
            <p />
            <img url="me3_img1.jpg"><![CDATA[some data]]></img>
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
            <p />
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
            <p />
            <img url="me3_img2.jpg"><![CDATA[some data]]></img>
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
            <p />
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
            <p />
            <img url="me3_img3.jpg"><![CDATA[some data]]></img>
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
            <p />
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
            <p />
            <img url="me3_img4.jpg"><![CDATA[some data]]></img>
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
            <p />
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
            <p />
            <img url="me3_img5.jpg"><![CDATA[some data]]></img>
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
            <p />
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
            <p />
            <img url="me3_img6.jpg"><![CDATA[some data]]></img>
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
            <p />
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
            <p />
            <img url="me3_img7.jpg"><![CDATA[some data]]></img>
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
            <p />
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
            <p />
            <img url="me3_img8.jpg"><![CDATA[some data]]></img>
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
            <p />
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
        </content>
    </review>
</game>
<!--more games-->
</reviews>
```

and then I want the output to look like this:

```
<forSale>
<game>
    <cover>me3_cover.jpg</cover>
    <title>Mass Effect 3</title>
    <publisher>Electronic Arts</publisher>
    <developer>BioWare</developer>
    <genre>Role-Playing</genre>
    <releaseDate>
        <yyyy>2012</yyyy>
        <mm>03</mm>
        <dd>06</dd>
    </releaseDate>
    <esrbRating>M</esrbRating>
    <platforms>
        <platform>X360</platform>
        <platform>PC</platform>
        <platform>PS3</platform>
        <platform>WIIU</platform>
    </platforms>
    <review>
        <critic>Kevin VanOrd</critic>
        <synopsis>
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
        </synopsis>
        <pros>
            <pro><![CDATA[some data]]></pro>
            <pro><![CDATA[some data]]></pro>
            <pro><![CDATA[some data]]></pro>
            <pro><![CDATA[some data]]></pro>
            <pro><![CDATA[some data]]></pro>
        </pros>
        <cons>
            <con><![CDATA[some data]]></con>
            <con><![CDATA[some data]]></con>
        </cons>
        <content>
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
            <p />
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
            <p />
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
            <p />
            <img url="me3_img1.jpg"><![CDATA[some data]]></img>
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
            <p />
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
            <p />
            <img url="me3_img2.jpg"><![CDATA[some data]]></img>
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
            <p />
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
            <p />
            <img url="me3_img3.jpg"><![CDATA[some data]]></img>
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
            <p />
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
            <p />
            <img url="me3_img4.jpg"><![CDATA[some data]]></img>
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
            <p />
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
            <p />
            <img url="me3_img5.jpg"><![CDATA[some data]]></img>
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
            <p />
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
            <p />
            <img url="me3_img6.jpg"><![CDATA[some data]]></img>
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
            <p />
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
            <p />
            <img url="me3_img7.jpg"><![CDATA[some data]]></img>
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
            <p />
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
            <p />
            <img url="me3_img8.jpg"><![CDATA[some data]]></img>
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
            <p />
            <![CDATA[some data]]>
        </content>
    </review>
</game>
<!--more games-->
</forSale>
```

The problem I'm having is firstly to say when the `<title>` tag in the `reviews.xml` and the `forSale.xml` match, then the review must be added else not. I must use xslt to do this and the code I have thus far is as follows:

```
<forSale>
<xsl:for-each select="document('forSale.xml')/forSale/game">
    <game>
        <xsl:copy-of select="cover" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="title" />
        <xsl:variable name="title" select="title" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="publisher" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="developer" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="genre" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="releaseDate" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="esrbRating" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="platforms"/>
            <xsl:template match="document('reviews.xml')/reviews/game">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="./title = $title">
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="./review" />
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>
    </game>

</xsl:for-each>
</forSale>
```

And then secondly I don't know how to copy the `<![CDATA[some data]]>` exactly like that.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the XSLT data model does not distinguish between plain text nodes and CDATA sections so whether your input has e.g. `<foo>some data</foo>` or `<foo><![CDATA[some data]]></foo>` is not modeled in the input tree the XSLT processor works with. Thus you can't ensure that such an element is copied as it is. You can however instruct the XSLT processor to output the contents of certain result elements as CDATA sections using e.g.

```
<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="foo bar"/>
```

would ensure that the serialized result tree of an XSLT transformation uses `<foo><![CDATA[some data]]></foo>` and `<bar><![CDATA[a & b]]></bar>`. This will however then happen for all elements of those names, not only for those that were copied from input having CDATA section contents.

Comment: Martin, there is nothing like "XSLT data model". You probably wanted to say "XPath Data Model", or "XML Infoset" ?

Comment: Well the "XPath data model" is used by XSLT (http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#data-model) so I don't see anything wrong in using the term "XSLT data model".

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the first part of the question is:
You can use the same think to access the second document as you did  for the first one:
Something like this should do:

```
                <xsl:for-each select="document('reviews.xml')/reviews/game[title = $title]">
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="review" />
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:for-each>
```

Update: Generate CDATA.

I do not know if and how it would be possible to test for CDATA in input. But you can test if there are character which would be escaped but you do not like to that and use CDATA.
Try something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains(.,'&lt;')">
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="."/>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of  select="."/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>   
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete solution of your problem is look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <forSale>
      <xsl:for-each select="document('Untitled1.xml')/forSale/game">
        <game>
          <xsl:copy-of select="cover"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="title"/>
          <xsl:variable name="title" select="title"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="publisher"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="developer"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="genre"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="releaseDate"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="esrbRating"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="platforms"/>
          <xsl:for-each select="document('Untitled2.xml')/reviews/game">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="./title = $title">
                <review>
                  <xsl:call-template name="checkChild">
                    <xsl:with-param name="self" select="self::node()/review"/>
                  </xsl:call-template>
                </review>
              </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </game>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </forSale>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="checkChild">
    <xsl:param name="self"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$self/child::node()">
      <xsl:message>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
      </xsl:message>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="self::node()/name() = 'pros'">
          <pros>
            <xsl:for-each select="pro">
              <pro>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
              </pro>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </pros>

        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="self::node()/name() = 'synopsis'">
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
          </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="self::node()/name() = 'cons'">
          <cons>
            <xsl:for-each select="con">
              <con>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
              </con>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </cons>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="self::node()/name() = 'content'">
          <content>

            <xsl:for-each select="child::node()">
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="self::text()">
                  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="self::node()/name()= 'img'">
                  <xsl:element name="{name()}">
                    <xsl:if test="@url">
                      <xsl:attribute name="url">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@url"/>
                      </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
                  </xsl:element>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
                  </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </content>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
          </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```